# JQuery Checkbox validation one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html and jquery code segments to validate at least one check box. I am new for jQuery so I can not validate this two check boxes. Please help me. Thank you

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label input-sm">Payement Type</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
             <span id="errfnBC9" style="color:red;font-size:8pt"></span>
             <input type="checkbox" name="cashactive" id="activecash" value="Cash" checked style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 11px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Cash
                  <input type="checkbox" name="creditactive" id="activecredits" value="Credit" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 11px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Credit<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

    if ($('#activecash').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('errfnBC9').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('errfnBC9').innerHTML = "**Please select at least one checkbox";
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If you're writing something for use on a real site, you could utilize the Formation validation library I built - http://www.github.com/ozzyogkush/formation - it does all kinds of element types including radio/checkboxes

Comment: also this particular use case would be better suited to a `radio` button since the user would only select one option, not more than one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use only with javascript or jquery .Apply with `onchange` event it will validate each time of the box checking.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
 $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change',function (){
  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
     $('#errfnBC9').html( "**Please select atleast one checkbox");
    }
    else{
      
        $('#errfnBC9').html( "");
   
    }
  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label input-sm">Payement Type</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <span id="errfnBC9" style="color:red;font-size:8pt"></span><br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cashactive" id="activecash" value="Cash" checked style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 11px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Cash
                                <input type="checkbox" name="creditactive" id="activecredits" value="Credit" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 11px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Credit<br>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an event listener to see when the state of the checkboxes is changing:

```js
$(".validate").on("change", function(e) {
    if($("input.validate:checked").length == 0) {
        $("#error").html("You must select one.");
    } else {
        $("#error").html("");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="cash" class="validate" checked /><label for="cash">Cash</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="credit" class="validate" /><label for="credit">Credit</label>

<p id="error"></p>
```